# How to export Customer with B2BUnit name and code in HMC Hybris?

Tags: export, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I need to create a repeatable data extract from HMC that includes the following customer fields:
-- Name
-- Email Address
-- Company Name (B2Bunit name)
-- Company ID (B2Bunit)

Is that possible with HMC export?
Thank you!

Comment: What you mean by repeatable extract ? a job with a schedule trigger ?

Comment: Export in HMC so any eligible user can run it. On demand process. I suspect I will have to create a custom translator that retrieves values from B2BUnit. Any ides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export your data via HMC export tool or HAC export tool you can try this impex script :

```
 insert_update Customer;name;uid[unique=true,allownull=true];company(locName[lang=en]);company(uid);
```

`Company` should be replaced by B2BUnit(Company) attribute name on your customer structure.

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Good news ;) ! So can you mark that the answer resloves the problem ? Thank you.